# Json parsing in flutter after null safety

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a simple json which I want to display sunrise and sunset times.

My Json looks like this

```
{
"SunRise" : "5.30:00",
"SunSet" : "6:30:00",
"MoonRise":"19:54:11",
"MoonSet":"7:50:55"
}
```

My Model Looks like this.

```
class AutoGenerate {
  AutoGenerate({
    required this.SunRise,
    required this.SunSet,
    required this.MoonRise,
    required this.MoonSet,
  });
  late final String SunRise;
  late final String SunSet;
  late final String MoonRise;
  late final String MoonSet;
  
  AutoGenerate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    SunRise = json['SunRise'];
    SunSet = json['SunSet'];
    MoonRise = json['MoonRise'];
    MoonSet = json['MoonSet'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['SunRise'] = SunRise;
    _data['SunSet'] = SunSet;
    _data['MoonRise'] = MoonRise;
    _data['MoonSet'] = MoonSet;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

MyFetch Mechanism.

```
Future<AutoGenerate> getData() async {
 
 final response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('MyURL'));
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
}
```

I want to build a set of cards for sun/moon rise/set. Below the mechanism to show how my widget is sent to card.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder<AutoGenerate>(
              future : getData(),
              builder: ( context,  AsyncSnapshot<AutoGenerate> snapshot) 
              {
               if (snapshot!.hasData) {
               return Container(
               child :    Card(
//                 margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                    elevation: 1.2,
                                    color: Colors.yellowAccent[100],
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                      child: Text('Sun Rise :'+snapshot.data.SunRise),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                  )
                                  }
                                  }
                                  )
                                  )
                                  )
                                  )
                                  }
```

I am getting an error on the **snapshot.data.SunRise** saying **"The property 'SunRise' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.** (Documentation)  Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

I have kind of tried all the options and also tried to assign the response to a variable and use that variable to show in the Card but gives me another error.

What is best way to move forward?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `?.` or `!` and if you add `!`, you should add after dot(.)

```
 Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: FutureBuilder<AutoGenerate>(
                        future: getData(),
                        builder:
                            (context, AsyncSnapshot<AutoGenerate> snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container(
                                child: Card(
//                 margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              elevation: 1.2,
                              color: Colors.yellowAccent[100],
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                child:
                                    Text("Sun Rise :  ${snapshot.data?.SunRise}")
                              ),
                            ));
                          } 
                        }))))
```

read more about  [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: Then there is a new error which comes up.      

 The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: add ? after all string

Comment: I have done that too.. Error does not go away. The error says.  

changed to this in the Model

late final String? SunRise;  

but still same error. Error does not change.

Comment: do you use null safe in your code? where you got error, UI or screen?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is null safe. not sure what else do I need to make this more null safe.  These errors can be seen only in the IDE. Android Studio IDE while tryng to develop a flutter app.

Comment: gimme the screenshot of your error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237414/discussion-between-purnasatyap-and-jahidul-islam).

Comment: https://ibb.co/LhcYLY4
https://ibb.co/BKJKWyy

Just incase to see the errors for others